How do I run only one function in my function app locally?
The documentation seems to suggest that I can specify which functions should start by specifying the functions of interest to run in my local.settings.json
I tried defining at the top level
{
  ...
  "functions": ["RunJustThisFunction"]
  ...
}

and at the Values level.
{
  ...
  "Values": {
    ...
    "functions": ["RunJustThisFunction"]
    ...
  }
  ...
}

But when I run the app I see all of the functions trying to execute.

FWIW, if I do this directly in my host.json it works as expected.

seems possible, still haven't figured it out though. see: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4575

I figured it out ... this issue on gh got me in the right direction.
local.settings.json
{
  ...
  Values: {
    ...
    "AzureFunctionsJobHost:functions:0": "SomeFunction",
    "AzureFunctionsJobHost:functions:1": "AnotherFunction",
    ...

  }
  ...
}

